# Component K2 is damaged, says class K2HelperHTML not found

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

My Joomla powered website was hacked several days ago, after it was cleaned and restored, a problem emerged.

On back-end, when I click `Components` -> `k2` and an fatal error appears:

```
Fatal error: Class 'K2HelperHTML' not found in ~/administrator/components/com_k2/k2.php on line 77
```

I compare this k2.php file with a working site's k2.php but no differenced was found.

Then I inpsected the file where class K2HelperHTML was defined, which I believe is `~\administrator\components\com_k2\helpers\html.php`, it doesn't show any differenct from a working site's corresponding file.

Now I'm stuck here, what should I do next to repair this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the most recent version? That would be a good place to start. Simply use the Joomla installer to install the latest version.

Comment: I thought about this, but I was wondering if reinstalling it would erase all my items

Comment: As long as you don't uninstall it won't hurt anything to install over the top of an existing install.

Comment: What about version? can I just install the newest version or do I need to install the exact version I had?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered same problem with fresh installed component and solution for me was pretty easy. All I had to do, was clear application cache.

To do it go to `System` -> `Clear Cache` and then click `Delete all`.